# Python Requests and TLS Lite

Tags: python, python-requests

Does anybody have experience combining Python Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) with TLS Lite (https://github.com/trevp/tlslite)?
TLS Lite has HTTPTLSConnection class to work with HTTPS but i have a lot of code written with Requests and would very like to reuse it.

Comment: requests is capable of speaking https - what specifically are you after?